# Как настроить javafx

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Переустановил Windos, соответственно пришлось переустанавливать и все программы.
Завершив эту процедуру,я открыл свой проект в Intelij IDEA (проект создавался с использованием javafx scene builder), но возникла проблема, некторые библиотеки javafx перестали распознаваться(как и код, связанный с графическим интерфейсом)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне делать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, нужно было поменять версию jdk на jdk-8u212